# Fórmula para Contar Valores Booleanos Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Boa noite pessoal,

estou tentando fazer um count com valores booleanos no power bi, usando fórmulas DAX, mas as fórmulas não retornam nenhum valor nos gráficos.

Alguém saber dizer qual o problema da fórmula DAX abaixo?

```
   SLA Chamado (Atrasado) = 
    CALCULATE
    (
        COUNTAX
        (
            FILTER(Chamado;Chamado[SLAExpirado] = TRUE());
            Chamado[SLAExpirado]
        )

     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver o problema é que sua fórmula retorna valores em branco para os casos em que o "SLA" não está expirado.

Tenta utilizar um IF para verificar o retorno e coloca algum valor caso o retorno seja 'nulo'

exemplo:

```
     SLA Chamado (Atrasado) = 
        IF((
        CALCULATE
        (
            COUNTAX
            (
                FILTER(Chamado;Chamado[SLAExpirado] = TRUE());
                Chamado[SLAExpirado]
            )

         )=1;1;0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não tenha necessidade de utilizar a função CALCULATE ao mesmo tempo em que usa a função COUNTAX. Tendo em vista que ambas as funções se fosse usadas separadas, iriam retornar um valor inteiro, que é o que você tá buscando. Dessa forma, eu tentaria apenas utilizar a fórmula COUNTAX. Ficando assim a sua fórmula:

```
SLA Chamado (Atrasado) = 
    COUNTAX
    (
        FILTER(Chamado;Chamado[SLAExpirado] = TRUE());
        Chamado[SLAExpirado]
    )
```